# How to select records from table1 which have table3 options in table2?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many

Let's say, I have three tables:

- table1: contains various records;
- table2: contains what records have what options;
- table3: contains options;

table2 contains foreign key of table1, and table3 -  thus specifying which table1 record has witch table3 option. table1 records can have multiple table3 options;

I'm trying to select table1 records by specifying their options, I need to be able to select any option\any option combination and display all table1 records which have this option combination, it can have additional options, but it must have the specified ones...

How would you write/build such a query?

note: I'm specifying what options to use from form..

imagine - table 1 contains products and table3 contains various details about products

User submits a form selecting check-boxes thus showing what details a product should have and I need to get all records which have these options ...

```
foreach($table1record as $detail){
  if($this->input->post('detail_{$detail['id']})){
    //option selected, continue building query ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM table1 as t1
 INNER JOIN table2 as t2
 WHERE t2.SomeColumn IN (SELECT SomeOtherCol FROM table3);
```

Comment: um.. i don't see where i specify the options i want to look for ..   right now i'm going over the records in table3 and look if user has checked the corresponding check-box, if so then look for this option..

Comment: You're right... You didn't give any of that info, nor any schema. I gave the general SQL approach; modify as needed.